# Minecraft PE Won't Work

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In MCPE on my apple device won't let me go in. Everytime I tap a world it takes me out of the game and to my homepage. I love Minecraft but ever since 0.16.0 came out it does this. Someone please help me with this. I deleted the game and got it back and deleted other apps and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are on an iOS device. From looking on Mojang's bug tracker it looks like it was a memory issue they did not afford for. This was an issue when version 0.16.0 was released. Since then, the game has updated to 0.16.1 and all reports are that the bug is gone.

Answer (score -1):

That happened to me as well, if you go into the App Store and update it again it should work; did for mine! Hope this helps.